# Pervasive SQL ADO.NET data provider

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, pervasive-sql

I have an asp.net, c# application using MSSQL 2008 server. At some point, i also want to insert some data into a pervasive v10 database. Was looking for the pervasive data provider from
http://www.pervasive.com/developerzone/access_methods/adonet.asp but the link has nothing!

Is there someone out there who can provider the dll or a better option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With PSQL v10 and v11, the provider is installed when the engine or client is installed by default.  If you need to integrate within Visual Studio, you would need the SDK which is under the title "ADO.NET 3.2" at http://www.pervasivedb.com/psqlv10/pages/default.aspx. I would also strongly suggest updating to PSQL v10 SP3 (10.31 Update 12). There have been bug fixes to both the PSQL engine and the ADO.NET provider.

Once you've verified it is installed, you can add a reference to the DLL (in C:\Program Files\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\ADONET32\Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.dll) in your C# application and use the objects.

Comment: Latest Pervasive SQL version is v11 at http://www.pervasivedb.com/psqlv11/pages/default.aspx